# Codename one ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to create a ListCellRenderer that consists of three text areas. In the constructor, I create an empty Container, set its layout, set Styles for the Text area and add the text areas to the container. This container id further added to the renderer component. Further, I am setting values to my TextAreas in the getListCellRendererComponent() method.
Following is my code:

```
 class PropertiesRenderer extends Container implements ListCellRenderer<PropertyAssessmentData> {

    private TextArea name = new TextArea("");
    private TextArea assessedValue = new TextArea("");
    private TextArea address = new TextArea("");
    private Label focus = new Label("");

    public PropertiesRenderer() {      
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Container con = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        con.getStyle().setBorder(Border.createBevelRaised());
        name.setEditable(false);
        name.getStyle().setBorder(null);
        con.addComponent(name);
        assessedValue.setEditable(false);
        assessedValue.getStyle().setBorder(null);
        con.addComponent(assessedValue);
        address.setEditable(false);
        address.getStyle().setBorder(null);
        con.addComponent(address);
        addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, con);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, PropertyAssessmentData value, int index, boolean isSelected) {
        name.setText("Name: " + value.getOwner_Name());
        assessedValue.setText("Total Value: " + value.getTotal_Value());
        address.setText("Address: " + value.getAddress());
        return this;
    }

    public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
        return focus;
    }

}
```

Now the problem is that it displays everything properly till the text area's have a single row. Once the text area's have multiple rows, it starts hiding the components. I think this has got something to do with CN1 calculating the size of the component without knowing the data it will contain and hence it defaults. Is this true ? Is there a workaround ? Attached is a screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renderers have uniform sizes I explained a bit more about why this is the case in a blog I wrote earlier this week: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/deeper-in-the-renderer.html

If you need more flexibility I suggest just using a container with box layout Y.

Comment: For the list I had created a Form with BorderLayout and the button was placed at South. (This made the button stick to the bottom). To overcome the above problem, I replaced the List with a container (BoxLayoutY) at north. But now the button at the south disappears when the north component is scroll-able.

Comment: You mean for the renderer not for the list, right? 
You shouldn't place scrollable components in the renderer.

Comment: Well, I removed the List component and used a container. In any case, this is now resolved. I placed the container at the center instead of north,

Comment: 404 for the link